# Arduino MPU error

Tags: arduino-nano, mpu6050

This is my code -

```
// Basic demo for accelerometer readings from Adafruit MPU6050

#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial)
    delay(10); // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("Adafruit MPU6050 test!");

  // Try to initialize!
  if (!mpu.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip");
    while (1) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MPU6050 Found!");

  mpu.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_8_G);
  Serial.print("Accelerometer range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getAccelerometerRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2_G:
    Serial.println("+-2G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_4_G:
    Serial.println("+-4G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_8_G:
    Serial.println("+-8G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_16_G:
    Serial.println("+-16G");
    break;
  }
  mpu.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG);
  Serial.print("Gyro range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getGyroRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_250_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 250 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 500 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_1000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 1000 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 2000 deg/s");
    break;
  }

  mpu.setFilterBandwidth(MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ);
  Serial.print("Filter bandwidth set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getFilterBandwidth()) {
  case MPU6050_BAND_260_HZ:
    Serial.println("260 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_184_HZ:
    Serial.println("184 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_94_HZ:
    Serial.println("94 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_44_HZ:
    Serial.println("44 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ:
    Serial.println("21 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_10_HZ:
    Serial.println("10 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_5_HZ:
    Serial.println("5 Hz");
    break;
  }

  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {

  /* Get new sensor events with the readings */
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  /* Print out the values */
  Serial.print("Acceleration X: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(" m/s^2");

  Serial.print("Rotation X: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.z);
  Serial.println(" rad/s");

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp.temperature);
  Serial.println(" degC");

  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}
```

and this is my error-

```
Adafruit MPU6050 test!
Failed to find MPU6050 chip
Adafruit MPU6050 test!
Failed to find MPU6050 chip
```

wires are connected properly

Comment: Please try the [I2C Scanner sketch](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/). That will show you if any device is found on the bus and which address it has. When I remember correctly the MPU6050 also has address pins to change the address. Maybe your MPU has a different address, than the library uses by default (seems to be `0x68` according to the library code on github)

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I thought the wires were connected properly...

Comment: the address is 0x68 I checked it

Comment: Knowing the address, there's not a lot [in the begin() function](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MPU6050/blob/2.0.5/Adafruit_MPU6050.cpp#L70) that can make it fail that isn't ultimately a wiring problem.  Determining (e.g. via `Serial.println`) which of these return statements is being executed may be of some use.

Comment: Have you checked with the I2C scanner sketch? You didn't specify that. I mentioned that sketch because it also confirms, that the I2C bus is working. And please share a schematic of your wiring

Comment: hey @timemage 
https://jpst.it/2xPxh 
This code is working but I want to use the other code, if it was a wiring problem then the code I mentioned now wouldn't work right? that's why I said the wiring is correct.                                                                                                                             by the way, thank yout for helping me I really appreciate it.

Comment: hi @chrisl I checked with the i2c scanner the and it says the address is **0x68**, by the way, thank you for helping me I really appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't looked at your other code and probably won't for a while.  But in short, no.  In particular the speed of the bus is under control of code and crappier wiring (the bus lines themselves and pullup resistors) support slower speeds.

Comment: Mhh, your code is just the basic_readings example from the Adafruit_MPU6050 library, so I would think that it is correct (the library is used by so many others without problems, so I don't think the library is at fault here). For me that doesn't leave much to analyze here. At that point I would normally check the wiring (and try pullup resistors like 4.7kOhm on the I2C lines, if not already done). I now that it worked with your other code, which is not using the library, but I cannot thing of anything else here.

Comment: If you have a logic analyzer (great tool, really cheap as USB device, like 10 bucks) you can monitor the I2C lines and look, what actually gets send and responded on the bus.